# Delete link is visible when deleting is not allowed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

I just tried to delete one of my questions:

- First the tool tip on the "delete" link shows "Vote to delete this post"

[image: tooltip]

- Clicking on the link showed a message box "Delete this post?". What happened with the voting?

[image: alert]

- I pressed OK... No luck.

[image: sorry]

- The question is not meant to be deleted in that way. It wants to be flagged to be deleted.
- I hovered the mouse on word "flag" on the red tooltip and a hand cursor appeared. I pressed the link and... No flag. It just closed the tooltip.
- Finally I flagged the question by using the flag link.

My question is, why do you show a delete link when it doesn't work?

I suppose the website saves resources and doesn't validate the delete link on every pageview.

However the procedure can probably be improved.

Comment: The delete link can be validated on click. If the user has no rights to delete or question is not appropriate for that, it can open directly "Flag" dialog. A short explanation can be shown. I read in other post you don't want to disable the link. No problem. A simple redirection will solve the confusion.

Comment: Redirections are confusing by nature. If I click `Delete` then I don't expect `Flag`.

Comment: Here is what I mean: [Screenshot](http://s22.postimg.org/aag2cbkch/dialog.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I think *possibly* merits some improvement here is the middle message box:

[image: Delete this post?]

Like you said, you know that you're *voting* to delete the post, and that's what the tooltip said, so it could be a bit confusing to people that the message says nothing at all about voting.

This is a fairly trivial complaint. The message box is simply confirming if you want to cast a vote to delete, and if you want to delete it, then the way you indicate that is by casting a vote. I don't think it's a show-stopper bug by any stretch of the imagination, neither do I think it's really tripping anyone up. Anyone can easily figure out what is meant.

Then again, it's also a fairly trivial fix. So maybe it's worth doing.

But I *don't* think that we should do either of these things:

- hide the "delete" link on posts that cannot be deleted
- automatically convert clicks on the "delete" link to flags

Both would be far too confusing.

With the first one, you'd see a post that you want to delete, try to delete it the way you normally do, and find that the delete link is missing. You would have no idea *why* it was missing, and you'd think it was just a bug. You'd either decide the site was broken and give up, or you'd come to Meta and report it. Either way, this is a workflow that is broken. Software (web software included) should *inform* the user, telling them *why* they can't perform this action and what they can do instead. Similar logic to what Joel Spolsky writes [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html):

> **Don't hide or disable menu items**
>
> A long time ago, it became fashionable, even recommended, to disable menu items when they could not be used.
>
> Don't do this. Users see the disabled menu item that they want to click on, and are left entirely without a clue of what they are supposed to do to get the menu item to work.
>
> Instead, leave the menu item enabled. If there's some reason you can't complete the action, the menu item can display a message telling the user why.

With the second one, you would probably think you'd clicked the wrong button. *"What? The flag dialog? I thought I clicked the "delete" link!"* So you'd click it again, and get the same result. *"Buggy software, can't even tell which link I'm clicking on."* So no, that's all wrong. Cases where automatic redirection is correct are quite rare. They're usually only appropriate to hide a mistake on the part of the developer (e.g. a page whose location has been changed should have old links redirect to the new one), not an ordinary and expected condition.

In my opinion, this message is very good:

[image: "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.]

It *informs* the user, telling them not only why something that would ordinarily be allowed (deletion) is not allowed in this specific case. And better yet, it *also* tells them how they can work around this problem.

Additionally, reading the explanation for why you cannot delete should give you pause and cause you to rethink whether you really want to delete it. In other words, you won't *always* want to flag for moderator attention, because this is a good reason *not* to delete a question.

The only downside of this approach that it adds an extra step to the workflow. Then again, after the first time or two, you learn this rule and stop trying.