# Should low quality posts locked for answer til they are reviewed?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I have noticed multiple times that there are questions which are flagged as low quality but there are still open for answers and similar.
In general I would say if a question is flagged like this, it should be locked til someone has reviewed it to decide if the question is okay for the site or needs to be deleted/closed or whatever.

[Pattern Matching Algorithm for Serial Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21856456/390177):
[image]

I would say this question is low quality and needs some improvements before unlocking it for answers.

What do you think?

Comment: If the site or reviewers don't remove the question. the user may decide to remove his own question if it is receiving a lot of down votes.

Comment: You can't remove your own question if there are already answers

Comment: @CSchulz Not true. There has to be at least one answer with a positive score for that to be enforced. If a question is bad enough, that's unlikely to happen before the down-votes, but I guess it depends on how closely the asker is paying attention.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Okay good to know. This isn't indicated in the error message, when trying to delete.

Comment: @CSchulz You could probably make a case that the delete button should be hidden or disabled if that action isn't possible, but [this has been rejected at least once](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191109/) and is typically not how our UI does things (well, sometimes - I can't see a `delete` link on your question, since I can't currently vote to delete it, because it isn't closed). I agree that the wording could be improved, but I think it can quickly become way too wordy. As an aside, for more details about closure rules, [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/).

Answer (score 4):

The entire reason that these posts are in the queue, and not just closed/deleted/locked/etc. automatically is that there is a sufficiently high false positive rate, or times where additional human guidance is needed/helpful, to warrant having reviewers take whatever actions are needed.  If you feel that the question cannot be answered due to its quality issues then vote to close it.  That's what the queue is there for.  If enough people agree, it will be closed, preventing answers.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A post enters into the low quality queue by a number of routes, including:

- An algorithm created by Stack Exchange.
- People flagging it.

Algorithms are not perfect and people can be prejudiced or wrong. If either the algorithm or the flagger is incorrect you're providing an appalling user experience by punishing someone for nothing.

If there is really a problem then the question/answer will be deleted shortly so there's really nothing to wrong about.

Comment: I believe there are two ways to get the algorithm to do it.  There's the "low quality auto flag filter" at the time of posting... but there's also a "low quality auto-flag (re?)triggered by down votes".  If you downvote something that is quite poor you *may* find it show up in the VLQ queue (some investigation into that [on M.P.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/downvoting-marginal-posts-can-trigger-their-inclusion-into-low-quality-queue)).